# How do I securly update a *BSD system?

Tags: security, freebsd, package-management, bsd

Security is a major concern.  Every major Linux distribution uses signed packages.  But the FreeBSD systems in the office downloading unsigned packages/ports via FTP.

Is there a solution that would allow me to securely update a *BSD on a malicious network?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [freebsd-update](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/updating-freebsdupdate.html) for official **binary** system updates.
When you upgrade packages from ports (e.g. with "portsnap" and "portmaster" like I do) the packages' source-files ARE signed with SHA256 checksums and verified before compilation, so I wouldn't worry about that.
Since it seems you're very much security-aware, I'd go with compiling ports from signed sources if I were you anyway.

Comment: +1 Yep, almost every update mechanism uses SHA256 and/or MD5 checksums to ensure packages and source files are correctly fetched.